# Returning string creates Tuple Python recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tuples

I have a recursive method in Python. Not sure if it helps but it checks how unbalanced AVL tree is. For example 10,20,30 is 'rr', 30,20,10 is 'll', 10,20,15 is 'rl' and 20,10,15 is 'lr'. 
Here is my code:

```
def rotation_type(bst, ptr='dummy'):
    if ptr == 'dummy':
        ptr = bst.root
    if ptr.left != None or ptr.right != None:
        if ptr.left != None:
            return 'l', rotation_type(bst,ptr.left)
        else:
            return 'r', rotation_type(bst,ptr.right)
```

My code works and all but it returns a Tuple. For example if my binary tree is [10,20,30] it returns `('r', ('r', None))`. Is there a way to return only a string like 'rr'? Sorry if this question has been asked before but I couldn't find it anywhere. Thanks in advance

Comment: What should be returned for nodes that have *both children present*? The node is then balanced, but you may want to recurse onwards in both children?

Comment: I already got function if both are present, if not i'm calling this function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to concatenate the recursive result, so you return a string each time:

```
return 'l' + rotation_type(bst, ptr.left)
```

Further remarks:

- Use `<something> is None` and `<something> is not None` to test for `None` values; `None` is a singleton.
- I'd use `None` as a default value rather than a string in your signature.
- `None` is a falsey value, you could just use `if ptr.left` and `if ptr.right`.
- You need to return something for the case where both children are missing.

Improved version:

```
def rotation_type(bst, ptr=None):
    ptr = ptr or bst.root
    if ptr.left:
        return 'l' + rotation_type(bst, ptr.left)
    elif ptr.right:
        return 'r' + rotation_type(bst, ptr.right)
    else:
        return ''
```

Comment: also at the function end, there should be `return ''`, to avoid `None` and `str` concat error

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I didn't think of this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, an easy fix is to **use string concatenation `+` over tuples `,`**:

```
def rotation_type(bst, ptr='dummy'):
    if ptr == 'dummy':
        ptr = bst.root
    if ptr.left != None or ptr.right != None:
        if ptr.left != None:
            return 'l' + rotation_type(bst,ptr.left)
        else:
            return 'r' + rotation_type(bst,ptr.right)
    return ''
```

You also have to return the empty string if nothing is returned (last line), since otherwise we will concatenate a string with a `None`-type, which will error.

I would also advice to use `None` over dummy, since this is usually the placeholder, instead there are really good reasons not to:

```
def rotation_type(bst, ptr=None):
    if ptr is None:
        ptr = bst.root
    if ptr.left != None or ptr.right != None:
        if ptr.left != None:
            return 'l' + rotation_type(bst,ptr.left)
        else:
            return 'r' + rotation_type(bst,ptr.right)
    return ''
```

You can still improve the code, but I leave this as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I didn't think of this. I'll accept Ghostly's solution because he was first.